# Visual Studio 2019 Edit and Continue is not working properly

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am working with "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019" version "16.6.1" but I am facing a problem debugging the code.

*Problem: If I put the debugger and change the code but no impact on the changes code. I have changes options (Edit and Continue Native Code) but not working.*

After single changes of code need to run the project and taking lots of time.

Issues Produce Steps:

1. I have taken a .net core 3.1 project
2. Point a debugger in c# code (Where a single line code 'string test="test"')
3. After coming the debugger location of C# code change the code (test="test code" and save the code) and press F10
4. Show a pop-up "Edit were made which cannot be complied.."
5. see the details : https://prnt.sc/10e8xp4

Note: I have changes E&C and other settings also but failed to solve the issues.
It's taking huge time to develop the project, because after changes the code need to run the project again.

Looking for solutions, Thanks.

Comment: What is the project type?

Comment: Using asp.net core 3.1

Comment: Have you checked https://superuser.com/a/1528661/57822? Can you be more specific on what you're changing (cshtml, cs, etc), if it's an MVC, Razor

Comment: Yes, I have checked this. It's working fine for cshtml, angular and others. but the problem in C# code. If I debug and change the code it showing a pop-up "Edit were made which cannot be complied..."

Comment: Is the complete message "Edits were made which cannot be compiled. Execution cannot continue until the compile errors are fixed"? Can you just post the minimal reproducible example and full error message?

Comment: Please see the updated post and error details here : https://prnt.sc/10e8xp4

Comment: Can't replicate it here, I made a string test = "blah", replace it with "blahblah" on breakpoint pause, and it just executes normally. Either update your VS or try replicating on an empty project first, this could be due to other dependencies in your app.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using now?

Comment: 16.8.5, if you update now you should get 16.9

Comment: My VS Version 16.9.0 but not working. Could you suggest to me any configuration changes or anything need to configure?

Comment: I don't know because I didn't make any change to my VS. Try resetting VS setting. Does it also happen to blank, empty MVC projects freshly created from the template?

Comment: Thanks, @Martheen for your time. I am going to fresh install and check again.

Comment: I have installed the latest version of VS2019 but not working still now. Option information of Debug here https://prnt.sc/10ebck2.

Comment: And this happen on a default VS setting (reinstalling don't automatically reset your config, especially if you've logged into your account) with default blank app? Then you should fill a bug report

Comment: Same problem here. I am using VS2019 and tried to solved this a year ago but could'nt. I thought I would try again and am seeing this is still an issue.

Comment: This problem is resolved... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664271/make-code-read-only-in-visual-studio-2019-while-debugging)